# Como fazer um for de requisições ajax?

Tags: javascript

Por que isso não funciona? digo ele mostra duas vezes meu alert e depois para, sendo que o valor de `aux_count` é 17.

```
for(var i = aux_cont; i > 0; i++ ){
    var eval_data = eval(obj_grafico[aux_cont].series);

    alert(aux_cont);
    alert(i);

    $.ajax({
        type:"POST",
        url:"../../tmp/cria_json_pan_servidor.php",
        data:{
            montante_y:obj_grafico[i].montante_y,
            tickInterval_y:obj_grafico[i].tickInterval_y,
            min_y:obj_grafico[i].min_y,
            max_y:obj_grafico[i].max_y,
            min_x:obj_grafico[i].min_x,
            max_x:obj_grafico[i].max_x,
            tickInterval_x:obj_grafico[i].tickInterval_x,
            filename:obj_grafico[i].filename,
        },
        cache:false
    });
}
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

abaixo como defino os valores do meu objeto:

```
obj_grafico[aux_cont] = {

        montante_y: montante_y,
        tickInterval: intervalo_y,
        min_y: min_y,
        max_y: max_y,
        min_x: min_x,
        max_x: max_x,
        tickInterval: intervalo_x,
        tickAmount: montante_x,
        series: seriesOptions,
        filename: hostname

    }
```

Comment: Pode alterar a imagem pelo código pf?

Comment: @LucasCosta alterei

Comment: Acho que seu for está errado, não seria `for(var i = 0; i < aux_cont; i++ ){`? E veja no console se tem alguma mensagem de erro..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eu acho que o seu for está errado...
Creio que o valor de aux_cont já esta em 17 antes do for
Tente da seguinte maneira:

```
for(var i = 0; i < aux_cont; i++ ){
    var eval_data = eval(obj_grafico[i].series);

    alert(aux_cont);
    alert(i);

    $.ajax({
        type:"POST",
        url:"../../tmp/cria_json_pan_servidor.php",
        data:{
            montante_y:obj_grafico[i].montante_y,
            tickInterval_y:obj_grafico[i].tickInterval_y,
            min_y:obj_grafico[i].min_y,
            max_y:obj_grafico[i].max_y,
            min_x:obj_grafico[i].min_x,
            max_x:obj_grafico[i].max_x,
            tickInterval_x:obj_grafico[i].tickInterval_x,
            filename:obj_grafico[i].filename,
        },
        cache:false
    });
}
```

Comment: aparece 17, 0 e depois acaba, porem esta com erro no console vou arrumar e te falo

Comment: Esse código ta esquisito... Por exemplo, qual a função da variavel eval_data, já que vc n usa ela pra baixo?(verifique se o console do navegador não esta apontando algum erro...) e me diga uma coisa só pra mim entender, o aux_count já vem com o valor de 17 e é imutável, certo?

Comment: Sim o eval foi uma tentativa de debug, o valor de 17 é preenchido de acordo com uma requisição feita antes, olha o erro que da que bizzaro (postei foto)

Comment: quando eu chamo obj_grafico[i].filename em outra função que não seja aquela que eu estou definindo minha variavel obj_grafico ele estoura esse erro, porque isso esta ocorrendo?

Comment: de uma olhada ou uma debugada no array obj_grafico. O erro diz que a propriedade 'filename' não consta lá.. Talvez o array não tenha 17 posições também.... Seria uma boa vc colocar seu código inteiro num jsfiddle ou até na sua pergunta msm, assim eu posso analizar o código melhor

Comment: coloquei como atribuo os valores do meu objeto, ve se está coerente. Matheus minha variavel do objeto só está mostrando se coloco o alert dentro da requisição ajax fora ele da erro, o que pode ser?

Comment: problema estava no for, é possível fazer varias requisições ajax